# I am trying to tighten my seat to keep it from rocking back and forth, but the bolt is stripped. this is a wide seat huffy

Tags: saddle

I was tightening my wide huffy seat and stripped the bolt, can I get just the bolt?

Answer (score 1):

in my experience, if you can't get the noise to stop by tightening, either one of two things is wrong. either you're tightening the wrong thing (noise is coming from elsewhere), or the two pieces are mismatched and don't mesh together perfectly. I had this happen with a handlebar that was 0.1mm different in diameter from the handlebar stem.  for a seat, i might try to look where else the noise might be coming from.

every time I got the setup right, I never had to overtighten enough to strip bolts (and I've stripped plenty).

Answer (score 0):

If you take your seat clamp bolt and nut to a hardware store you might find something that will work.

[image: picture of seat clamp]

You can also find the whole seat clamp online. The key is finding something that fits your seat post.